# Error 6624 : A Winsock virtual circuit was reset remotely

Tags: sql, winsock, advantage-database-server

We just installed a new `Advantage Server 11.1` on Linux (before used on netware)

When I run a query with the SPACE command from a SQL openquery, I got this error:

```
Error 6624:  A Winsock virtual circuit was reset remotely.
```

And the Linux service crashes, I must restart it.

If I run the same query with the old server, everything works fine.

Example of a query with the error:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t 
WHERE t.Key = SPACE(2) +  '776782'
```

Why does the SPACE command crash the Linux service ?

Comment: This should be a vendor technical support question. Did you try asking in their forums? You can find them [here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/).